# Codeigniter custom validation message?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I want to display validation message in "arabic" so i used:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('required','my message');
```

but this will return  "my message" only.

is there a way to add label for each field within my message so it's look like.

```
label "my message"
```

example:

```
<input type="text" name="field1">
<input type="text" name="field2">
```

output:

```
field1 my message
field2 my message
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in the user guide;

> If you include %s in your error string, it will be replaced with the "human" name you used for your field when you set your rules.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors

You would change your code, to this;

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('required','%s my message');
```

This would then use the name of the filed, you set in the validation rules.

Or, you could translate the field names;

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#translatingfn